# Tortoise git fails with No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey)

Tags: windows, git, tortoisegit

I'm at a loss here. I had tortoise working fine but something changed.  Now whenever I try to commit or pull from a remote repo I get

```
git.exe push --progress  "origin" master:master

FATAL ERROR: Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey)
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.


git did not exit cleanly (exit code 128) (1250 ms @ 3/23/2014 10:18:15 AM)
```

I have the `GIT_SSH` env var set to `C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY\plink.exe` and I have `pagaent.exe` running with my loaded private keys. github has my public keys.

Running the same command in the console

`git.exe push --progress  "origin" master:master` works just fine though! I've tried uninstalling tortoise, upgrading git, creating a new ssh key, nothing seems to work.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. I had installed [Gow](https://github.com/bmatzelle/gow) at some point which came with a version of pageant which I was spawning. This version of pagaent is somehow different than the one that comes with Putty and so tortoise was failing. When I ran the version of pagaent that comes with Putty everything finally worked again.

Answer (score 1):

It is better to use the one from TortoiseGit.

It is called `TortoiseGitPlink`.

More QA is done tightly with TortoiseGit.